# What does this sentence mean? Is it a run-on?

Tags: meaning, grammar, grammaticality

From the Big Short movie:

> But some of the fresh fish doesn't sell. I don't know why. **Maybe it just came out halibut has the intelligence of a dolphin.**

I can't discern the subject of the sentence. It seems a run-on.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in this sentence "it just came out (that) halibut has the intelligence of a dolphin", that-clause is the subject of the verb 'came'. Not a run-on sentence.